# My Facebook Game App is not appearing in users' 'Games Collection'

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

A few weeks/months ago, Facebook has introduced the new 'Games Section' (or 'Collection') to user profiles. A while ago I noticed that our game is not listed there among the other games played by that particular user. Our game has been available on Facebook and in the App Center for several months, and is for all intends and purposes an average ranked and used Arcade game, approved by Facebook and all.

According to Facebook's developer description no special code change is needed for a game to be listed in a user's Games Collection (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/03/27/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/), so I am at a loss as to what the reason for our game not being listed may be. I am not very experienced as a Facebook developer, so I may be missing something crucial. I searched the web and asked in the Facebook Developer Group, without any success.

A while ago I noticed that the game app setting was set to the category 'other', probably as a result of Facebook recently removing the 'Action & Arcade' category the game previously was categorized as from the app center. But I have since changed the app's category to 'Games - Arcade', which has been submitted to and approved by Facebook over a week ago. So that did not seem to be the reason.

The game is properly listed under a user's 'likes' and on his feed as '*friend* recently played', so I don't think that any missing graphical assets are the problem either.

If anyone has some insight on the new Games Section/Collection and what I could be missing, that would be most helpful.